# Javascript undefined is not an object async/await issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, async.js

I am relatively knew to React Native, JS and coding in general. I am getting the following error thrown in my code, but I am asking it on here because I believe it is evidence of a larger whole in my understanding. Specific fixes for my issue would be appreciated, but high level explanations would be more useful and beneficial to the community.

Note: I purchased the API functionality of this app from a programmer and got it working no problem. I do not fully understand async and await and believe this might be why I am getting an issue. When I comment out the findCriteria() function, everything runs smoothly and I pull in tweets; however when left in the program I get the following error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0): 
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'parsedArray.reduce')
```

My code is as follows:

```
async componentDidMount()


{    
    let twitterRest = new TwitterRest(); //create a new instance of TwitterRest Class   
    let twitts = await twitterRest.pullTimeLine('google'); //pull the Google TimeLine

function findCriteria(array, type){

  parseArray = (array, type) => {array.map((tweet) => {
    return tweet[type];
  })};
  let parsedArray = parseArray(array, type);

  findAvg = (parsedArray, array) => {parsedArray.reduce((totalV,currentV) => {
    return totalV + currentV;
  }, 0)/array.length};
  let avg = findAvg(parsedArray, array);

  findDiffs = (parsedArray, avg) => {parsedArray.map((index) => {
    return avg-index;
  })};
  let diffs = findDiffs(parsedArray, avg);

  findCriteria = (diffs, array, avg) => {(diffs.reduce((totalV,currentV) => {
    return totalV + currentV;
  }, 0)/array.length) + avg};
  let solution = findCriteria(diffs, array, avg);

  return solution;
};

let rtCriteria = findCriteria(twitts, "retweet_count");
this.setState({rtCriteria: rtCriteria});
```

I am trying to find standard deviation fyi.

Thank you, very much.

Comment: Your `parseArray` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Add `return` statement in all sub functions. like `parseArray = (array, type) => { return array.map((tweet) => { return tweet[type]; }) };`. same for `findAvg`, `findDiffs` etc.

Comment: Duh... Thank you.